# How to change color of view fade in CATransition

Tags: ios, swift, animation, presentviewcontroller

I'm implementing a custom CATransition so I can presentViewController from the left or right instead of the bottom, but am encountering an interesting issue with what the CATransition does.

Here is my code:

```
let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 2

transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault)
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
self.view.window?.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
```

Everything works as expected with the view that is being presented, but what happens to the view that is being replaced is what is interesting. It slowly fades to black, which creates a nasty black flash before my new view is fully animated in.

As seen in the image below, the closer my new view comes to being fully animated in, the darker the old view becomes. It reaches full black right before the view is fully transitioned in.

[image]

Comment: why do you animate Window? why not animate the self.View.Layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can direct transit the view.layer and change color the windows.

```
 @IBAction func test(_ sender: Any){

let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 2

transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default)
transition.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft

self.view.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)

}
```

If you want the color will not flashing, just set both destination color to the same value :

```
    let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 2

    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default)
    transition.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft

    self.view.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    self.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    self.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)

}
```

You can even add a customized animation to get what color transition you need.

```
    @IBAction func test(_ sender: Any){

    let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 2

    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default)
    transition.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft

 let colorAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
 colorAnimation.duration = 1.5
 colorAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default)
colorAnimation.toValue = UIColor.black.cgColor
colorAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.red.cgColor



 self.view.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
self.view.window?.layer.add(colorAnimation , forKey: nil)
self.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is happing because of default functionality of **CATransition**. You need to change color of window to avoid that.